# Run multiple virtual machines on a virtual server

Tags: virtual-machines, intrusion-detection, distribution, microsoft-virtual-server

Is it possible to run multiple virtual machines on a virtual server? I am on a project and I want to run an Intrusion Detection System as distributed using many ubuntu virtual machines. Is it possible to be done on a virtual server which runs Ubuntu?

Comment: @Michael Hampton it is a differrent one am asking about multiple virrtual machines on a virtual SERVER.

Comment: If you're trying to say that your virtual host is running a server "level" virtualisation product (for example, VMware ESXi compared to VMWare workstation) then yes Michael misunderstood you, *because* your question is unbelievably basic - what else would a virtual server *do* but run multiple virtual guests?

Comment: If you're saying that you want to run virtual guests inside another virtual guest but your question is somehow different because the top level virtual guest or the virtual host are servers then you're wrong and it's still a duplicate. Nothing magical happens because someone said "server"... In any case, with respect, this either a very poorly researched or very poorly written question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In *principle*, **yes** it is possible.

**However**

If you want to use 64bit guests within your Ubuntu VM, you will need VT-x (or the AMD equivalent) exposed into your Ubuntu box.

As far as I know, only VMware vSphere (ESXi) can do this - requests to add this into VirtualBox have been [strongly](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) [resisted](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20589).

Your other option is to use containerisation methods such as LXC, OpenVZ or Docker to run multiple VMs without full virtualisation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean run a hypervisor inside an existing VM? if so then yes but it depends on the hypervisor your existing VM is running on and also the hardware it's running on - but yes it can be done.